# Why class constructor generates destructors for its members?

Tags: c++

### Let's start with the warm-up.

I created a class template whose destructor just cannot be instantiated without compiler activating `static_assert`:

*File: M.hpp*

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct M
{
    M(){}
    ~M()
    {
        static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "no type can pass this");
    }
};
```

Next I used this class in two different ways: allocate it on heap and allocate it on stack:

*File main.cpp*

```cpp
#include "M.hpp"

int main()
{
    M<int> *pmi = new M<int>(); // does compile
    M<int> mi;                  // doen't compile
}
```

Allocating it on a heap `M<int> *pmi = new M<int>();` works. It is so as we only use constructor and don't need destructor. The rules for class template implicit instantiation [say](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Implicit_instantiation):

> ... unless the member is used in the program, it is not instantiated ...

Allocating it on stack `M<int> mi;` doesn't work as compiler definitely need to instantiate the destructor.

So far so good, clear rules.

### Let's get to the point.

I wrote another class which uses `M` as a member:

*File X.cpp*

```cpp
#include "M.hpp"

struct X
{
    X() = default;
    ~X() = delete;

private:
    M<int> m_;
};
```

I deleted the destructor intentionally because I don't want it to interfere anyhow with my experiment. 
Constructor is defaulted which in my understanding should only generate constructor of `M<int>`, its only member, and call it.
To my surprise this is not the case. `X()` also tries to generate the destructor of `M<int>`:

*File main.cpp*

```cpp
#include "X.hpp"

int main()
{
  X* px = new X();
}
```

and this is what I get from a compiler:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp
In file included from X.hpp:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
M.hpp: In instantiation of ‘M<T>::~M() [with T = int]’:
X.hpp:5:3:   required from here
M.hpp:7:29: error: static assertion failed: no type can pass this
     static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "no type can pass this");
```

**The question is**: why during the instantiation of the default constructor a compiler tries to instantiate a destructor for a member class template if it is not needed? If it is indeed needed could you point me at the documentation where it is stated?

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of your `X` *potentially invokes* destructors of its member subobjects for obvious reason: if an exception occurs during construction, everything that has been successfully constructed has to be destructed.

> **10.9.2 Initializing bases and members**
>
> **12** In a non-delegating constructor, the destructor for each potentially constructed subobject of class type is potentially invoked (15.4). [ Note: This provision ensures that destructors can be called for fully-constructed subobjects in case an exception is thrown (18.2). —end note ]

http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#12

Comment: I thought (maybe I'm mistaken) that default implementations of ctors are `noexcept` if possible, which should be the case for `M` and thus also for `X` here. So why is the dtor still potentially invoked, if no exception can be thrown?